# To calculate the average speed in 2 trips

Tags: average

A question as below:

A man initially travels 80 km at 32 km/hr and then the next 160 km at 40 km/hr. The average speed for the first 160 km of the tour is:

A. 25 km/hr

B. 34.2 km/hr

C. 35.56 km/hr

D. 40 km/hr

E. 44.2 km/hr

Here is how I calculate it:

Time1 = 80/32 ≈ 2.56 hour

Time2 = 160/40 = 4 hour

Average speed for the first 160 km is: 160/ (2.56 + 2) ≈ **35.07**
(2.56 hours spent on the first 80km and 2 hours spent on the second 80km)

It’s close to the answer C but not exactly? Am I doing it the right way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$80/32=2.5$, not $2.56$.  Then you'll get C.  [C]heers.

Comment: You may mark an answer as accepted once you think your problem is resolved

Comment: @J Tg, thank you for your help. I will. I am just want to give it some time as interesting to see if there're other opinions.

Comment: haha you're absolutely correct in everything else

Answer (score 1):

hint : the time should not be total time of the journey but it should be the time in which you journey first 160KM of total ( 160 + 80 ).